# Missing [X] button in dojo dialog box to close the window

Tags: dojo

For some reason, I am not able to see the [X] button to close the dialog box.
I tested examples from dojo website. Everything works but [X] button does not show up.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before, and if I recall correctly, it has to do with the Dijit theme not being set up properly. Could it be that you're not including the appropriate CSS file for the theme you're using? Or perhaps you don't even have a theme specified in your test page?

This reference page may help: http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit-themes